# jQuery trigger behaving strangely after a load request

Tags: jquery

I have created a history api-ish script with jQuery and also a AJAX script to show the news feed, both are in different script files. I need the news feed to load when a link is clicked and since I have a refresh feed button I have just tried to trigger the click of that.

However, the loading of the news feed after a link click and the triggered click is behaving strangely. It simply flashes and then disappears straight away so not too sure what is happening. I have tried changing all function to live but still no avail.

I should add that the feed script works on page refresh and on the click of the refresh feed button, so when the history api script is bypassed.

I can't create a jsfiddle as it references lots of files and databases.

Here is the history API-ish script:

```
$("a#click").click(function() {
    var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#main").load(addressValue + " #load"); 
    $("#refreshFeed").trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

And the feed script:

```
//Get feed on load
$.get("phpscripts/getFeed.php",function(result){
    $("#newsFeed").html(result);
}); 

//Get feed on click
$("#refreshFeed").live('click', function(){
    $.get("phpscripts/getFeed.php",function(result){
        $("#newsFeed").html(result);
    }); 
});
```

Note: Both scripts are triggered on doc ready.

Comment: create function for feedrfersh and call this on both cases

Comment: Do you have prior function calls on the #refreshFeed div could be responding to that too

Comment: @FemiOni no i do not. The only function on that div is the click funtion.

Comment: #load seem like an HTML Element so does $('main').load(address +'#load') might not be leading anywhere or behave strangely

Comment: @FemiOni both are html elements. The #load div is loaded into the #main div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am not sure if it works like that you are asking jquery to load a string value(addressValue) and an element(#load) possiblities are that jquery loads the href in addressValue and overwrites with element(#load) therefore the flash. try

```
alert(addressValue + $('#load'))
```

to see what you are parsing in then i will also suggest that if addressValue is an address of a page or element then try

```
$('#main').load(addressValue)
```

and see what happens from there you can figure out how to go

Comment: I am actually asking jQuery to load the element from the string into #main. The addressValue is an address to the clicked link and the #load div is in the linked address and this works fine. Strange thing though, when I set the alert the alert is sent twice this must be something do to with my problem.

Comment: can you please just try the .load() without the #load and see what happens. i think it makes life easier. the triggered part of you script looks fine.

Comment: I did, it loads the whole page that was referenced by the address Value into #main.

Comment: ok now i get you. you are trying to load a div in the address into main. if using load() without #load loaded and stayed(not flashed) on your page maybe you need a different implementation

Comment: Any ideas on what this implementation maybe? I am not asking you to code for me but I really have no idea where to go.